# Can I load html pre-written video as blob or dataurl?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm trying to download video on local html file, which doesn't work with href='normal path'.

Tried to load with XMLHttpRequest or fetch API, but none of these worked since this app have to run completely server-free.

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const src = video.src;

const a = document.createElement("A");
a.href = src;
a.download = 'video.mp4';

a.click()
```

I expected this would succeed, but it just shows video in internal chrome video player. What Should I do?

Comment: Downloads are probably restricted in `file://` protocol the same way `XMLHttpRequest ` is for security reasons. Why do you need to download a local file in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl Because I don't have any access to web servers. So you mean I can't do it?

Comment: Not sure what app is for but spinning up a localhost server is very easy also